# Recommendations on how to run daily scripts automatically and output to a network directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have several mundane daily/weekly scripts I run manually which I would like to automate and output to a directory, I am looking for recommendations on solutions anyone has currently working.

I have been reading up on SSIS packages via visual studio but I have not been able to get this to work as of yet, I wondered if there is any easier options?

I run most of my scripts in MySQL, although I do have some in MSSMS to.

Many Thanks

Comment: To automate SSIS you need SQL Job Agent on an Instance of SQL. Thereby you can automate scripts, insert data, move data to a directory or a database if you like. It can handle both MySQL and T-SQL

Comment: For periodic tasks, there is a TaskScheduler built into Windows. (`%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc`)

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your feedback, the SQL job agent is more for a sysadmin/dba role after a google it seems, I am a basic SQL user and only have access to run scripts on either MySQL and MSSMS, I thought if I could go down the SSIS route I could automate daily reporting from a normal user level, either by using visual studio or some other form of application. I wasn't aware TaskScheduler could run SQL tasks Stephan? Interesting